# cookie is setting to 1 hours instead of passed maxAge value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my file I've got a cookie that always sets to 1 hour by default even if I define `maxAge` 12 seconds

```
 res.cookie("my-cookies", req.body.id_token, {maxAge: 12000, httpOnly: false});
```

Comment: 12000 is not 12 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about gatsby but this also works, first use cookieParser as middleware

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
app.use(cookieParser)
```

and in your routes use this:

```js
res.cookie("my-cookies", req.body.id_token, {
      expires: new Date() + 12000
    });
```

also if the above solution didn't work visit this [site](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/issues/30)